# Logging Events in Application in Google App engine when implementing application in Java

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I need to log events in the logs of administrative console of Google App Engine. Here http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/logging.html its have been said about python. I have tried to save logs using

```
import java.util.logging.Logger;
....
public class ... {
...
Log.info("ivisdddd");
}
```

but its giving error (Error for /Visd java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/mortbay/log/Log at...). Please tell how to log in the GAE from Java application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything about logging in GAE/Java is in the reference documentation:

http://code.google.com/intl/en/appengine/docs/java/runtime.html#Logging

Comment: I am getting error, when i use log.info("") its not recognized, and when i use Log.info("") i get this -[ Error for /Visd java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/mortbay/log/Log at...] error, plz help

Comment: yes ofcourse, i had imported import java.util.logging.Logger; as above in the question and also as mentioned in the google site.

Comment: Log is not a class from java.util.logging. Use Logger.getLogger("someName").info("some message").

Comment: I have tried with this : Logger.getLogger("VISDD").info("some message"); and now there is no error but I am not able to find the log entry in the administrative console. Please help.

Comment: Have you configured logging as described in the documentation, so that the VISDD logger doesn't reject INFO messages?

Comment: You might be missing this code: `private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(MyServlet.class.getName());`